# Get Master branch from latest to previous commit without reverting all commits in between

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

what I am trying to do in my git repo is reverting the master branch from its latest commit to a previous one back in time. Let's say that my master branch history looks like this:

CommitA
||
CommitB
||
CommitC
||
CommitD
||
CommitE
||
CommitF
||
LatestCommit

what I am trying to do is bring my master branch from **LatestCommit** to **CommitB** .
I don't want to revert commit after commit since there are quite many in between.
What I tried was branching out from **CommitB** to a separate branch (let's call it **BranchCommitB**), pushing my new branch and then creating a pull request to merge it into master. Problem is that Azure Devops doesn't see any file change, even though if I go in the Master branch and in the BranchCommitB branch the files are different.

Comment: It's a bit unclear whether you want to create a new commit after LatestCommit that has the same contents as CommitB, or you want CommitB to become the latest commit and discard all newer commits.

Comment: (Fortunately, the duplicate answers both.)